# Derivative of exponent

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponentiation

Looking to solve :

$$ \frac{d}{dx}[2^{0.5x}]$$

The multiplication and X value in the exponent is confusing me. Help? Thanks!

Comment: What's confusing _me_ here is the colon. What does that mean in this context?

Comment: I think all he is trying to say with "$d/dx:$" is "derive the following term with regards to $x$". As Henning implied, that is not the way the notation is generally used.

Comment: @jesterjinx See my edit, this should help you be clearer to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help you to rewrite $2^{0.5x}$ as $2^{0.5 x} = e^{ln(2^{0.5x})} = e^{0.5x \cdot ln(2)}$. Are you familiar with why this re-writing works? Can you think of how to derive it now in the last way I wrote it?

If you still have problems, let me know and I can answer in more detail.

Comment: Not really familiar with it all! Or maybe I am, and I just forgot...I tend to forget a lot about what I learn in maths for some reason...Please explain in more details why this rewriting works!

Comment: Are you familiar with the exponential function and the natural logarithm? They are inverse functions of each other, so $exp(ln(x))=x$ or with the $e$ notation we would have $e^{ln(x)}=x$.

Now the logarithm function has the following general property: $ln(a^b)=b \cdot ln(a)$.
Together, this means that you can rewrite any number $a^b$ as $e^{ln{(a^b)}}$. Now you can use the logarithm rule in the exponent and you get $e^{ln{(a^b)}} = e^{b \cdot ln(a)}$. Then you can use the common derivation rules for the exponential function to derive this. Since $a=2$ in your problem $ln(2)$ is constant.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-wJkWBkYxQWA/V2cAkMU25qI/AAAAAAAAAKM/RfKgpkCwqdUFxjSOaRzgK6h6uk_yn9f8wCCo/s2048/%255BUNSET%255D).

So far, this seems good?

I had to find the derivative.

Comment: Careful, the re-writing is not in itself the derivative! You still need to take the derivative of $e^{0.5x \cdot ln(2)}$ on the left hand side after the substitution. The term $(2^{0.5x})'$ turns into $(e^{0.5x \cdot ln(2)})'$. Then you can use the knowledge that $(e^{cx})' = ce^{cx}$ where $c$ is any constant like $0.5 \cdot ln(2)$.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-nMzbY6_7--U/V2cIg6LGPqI/AAAAAAAAAKc/aKBDLtv2Cvw_iKMGSZGlR6bmaJrq39L8gCCo/s2048/%255BUNSET%255D).

Would this appear better? If we're asking for the "Exact answer", is it better to calculate $0.5*ln(2) ?

Comment: The exact answer would keep the term as $ln(2)$. Every calculation of that term will lead to imprecision because $ln(2)$ is irrational. 

Your answer looks correct to me but you can use $b \cdot ln(a) = ln (a^b)$ again at the end to rewrite this to $0.5 \cdot ln(2) = ln(2^{0.5}) = ln(\sqrt{2})$. That makes it nicer.

Answer (score 2):

This is something called logarithmic differentiation, the technique as I learned it goes like this, and makes use of implicit differentiation and thinking of $d$ as an operator which can be applied to both sides of an equation. Setting:
$$y= 2^{.5x}$$
We have the relationship between $x$ and $y$ (think implicit function material) 
$$\ln(y)=.5x\ln(2)$$
Then, applying the $d$ operator
$$d[\ln(y)]=d[.5x\ln(2)]\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{y}=.5\ln(2)dx $$
As requested, we have the LHS because 
$$d[\ln(y)]=\frac{1}{y}*dy$$ by the chain rule, first taking the derivative of $ln$ and then multiplying by the derivative of the inside, here $y$, which is $dy$. Might be worth reviewing implicit differentiation.

Then solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=.5\ln(2)y=.5\ln(2)2^{.5x} $$

Which is also the general derivative of $c^{ax}$. Give it a shot.

Comment: Why is $$d[\ln(y)] = \frac{dy}{y}$$ ? 

And thanks a lot for all the answers! Really appreciated! :D

Comment: I will edit in an extra step.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac { d }{ dx } \left( { 2 }^{ 0.5x } \right) ={ 2 }^{ 0.5x }\ln { 2 } { \left( 0.5x \right)  }^{ \prime  }={ 2 }^{ 0.5x }\ln { \sqrt { 2 }  } $$

Answer (score 0):

You have to write

$$2^{0.5x}=e^{0.5x\log(2)},$$

so

$$\frac d{dx}\left(e^{0.5x\log(2)}\right)=0.5\log(2)e^{0.5x\log(2)}.$$

Finally,

$$\frac d{dx}(2^{0.5x})=\frac{\log(2)}2 2^{0.5x}.$$