# Determine the equation of the tangent to y=3(2^x) at x= 3

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I am not quite sure how to go about this question. If you could help that would be great.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Do you know how to compute the derivative of $y=3\times 2^x$?

Comment: well i thought the derivative of the above would be y=(ln6)(6^x) if we multiplied the 3 by the 2^x. Or if we were to use product rule then it would be (6^x)(ln2)

Comment: There's no $6^x$ here....Try writing the function as $y=3e^{x\ln 2}$.  Makes it easier to differentiate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Derivative of exponent](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832370/derivative-of-exponent)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Differentiating:

$$y'=3\cdot2^x\ln2$$

(Notice when differentiating a known base to a variable power, the derivative is the expression times the natural logarithm of the base)

At $x=3$, where $y'=m$ (slope):

$$y'=3\cdot2^3\ln2$$

Simplifying:

$$y'=24\ln2$$

So the slope is $24\ln2$.

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it.

Comment: @Olivia No problem

Comment: and when we need to find b, for the equation we just sub in 3 into the primary equation. Correct?

Comment: @Olivia That's right. I should add that the mistake you made was deriving the expression $(3\cdot2)^x$, not $3(2^x)$.

Comment: Thanks! And I never even voted. Not me sorry.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write $2^x \equiv e^{x \ln 2}$, then proceed to differentiate as normal to find the tangent slope. Indeed, it is a fact that $a^x \equiv e^{x \ln a}$.